# SSSD, openLDAP and nested groups

Tags: linux, openldap, sssd

I am trying to figure out how to structure my ldap and/or configure sssd to read membership of nested groups.

Something like this works for normal group membership:

```
DN: cn=server-admins,ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=com
groupOfNames (structural)
posixGroup (auxiliary)
memberUid userName1
memberUid userName2
```

and the sssd.conf doing something like:

```
[sssd]
config_file_version = 2
domains = default
services = nss, pam
full_name_format = %1$s

[domain/default]
debug_level = 2
id_provider = ldap
auth_provider = ldap
cache_credentials = True
ldap_uri = ldaps://ldapserver:636
ldap_search_base = dc=example,dc=com
# start searching here
ldap_user_search_base = ou=People,dc=example,dc=com
# search these people
ldap_group_search_base = ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=com
ldap_group_nesting_level = 10
simple_allow_groups = server-admins
```

if I `id userName1` I get the `server-admins` membership and can log in with that user.

However, what I'd like to do is something like this:

```
DN: cn=server-admins,ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=com
groupOfNames (structural)
posixGroup (auxiliary)
member cn=jobTitleGroup1,ou=Roles,dc=example,dc=com
```

Then have membership of the `jobTitleGroup1` contain the people:

```
DN: cn=jobTitleGroup1,ou=Roles,dc=example,dc=com
groupOfNames (structural)
posixGroup (auxiliary)
memberUid userName1
memberUid userName2
```

The problem is sssd only seems to recognise the memberUid attribute, and doesn't seem to see/search the nested group membership of `jobTitleGroup1`.

So I don't know how to do nested groups, and/or don't know how to get sssd to read the membership of nested groups.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two weeks later, I found the answer. Two things were the issue, one of which was because of the first.

The first issue was that because I configured ldap with the rfc2307bis schema, my groups are using groupOfNames, and the "member" attribute.

However sssd was not recognising membership unless I used "memberUid". The memberUid was the second problem.

in sssd.conf under domain/default I needed the following:

```
[domain/default]
ldap_schema = rfc2307bis
ldap_group_object_class=groupOfNames
ldap_group_member=member
```

so then my permissions group could be:

```
DN: cn=server-admins,ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=com
groupOfNames (structural)
posixGroup (auxiliary)
member cn=jobTitleGroup1,ou=Roles,dc=example,dc=com
```

and my role group could be:

```
DN: cn=jobTitleGroup1,ou=Roles,dc=example,dc=com
groupOfNames (structural)
posixGroup (auxiliary)
member uid=userName1,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com
member uid=userName2,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com
```

Comment: I have similar issue, however, my `jobTitleGroup1` is not a posixGroup.
This works for `nss-pam-ldapd`, but not SSSD.